How to position a deep tree Widget on top of everything else (equivalent to z-index) in Flutter
I have a Widget tree like:

App Body

Column of Widgets

A Widget with a Table

Each TableRow has a TableCell

And in a TableCell there is a Widget that spans over multiple Rows and Columns of the table (like a number circled with a huge circle, also multiple numbers can have these circles).









The table has variable alignment based on the data in the table. All the circles need to be on top of all the cells. And each circle has a shadow. Ideally a circle would not cast a shadow on another circle.
The issue is, with placing the "circle" in a TableCell, it is covered by the next cell/row. In html I would use z-index which looks like it is not present in Flutter. Is there another option how to do that, other than constructing another stacked layer of invisible table just to get the position of the circles right?
The final result should look something like this:

Thank you!

Please share the image you want to create.

Sure, I added it to the question body.

Please share code for more references.

I recommend that you create a Custom Table Cell which would have a boolean to add or not a circle to the cell and I will add this CustomTableCell to the TableRow() of the Table like these:
class TableWithOverlays extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Table(
      border: TableBorder.all(),
      columnWidths: {
        0: FlexColumnWidth(1),
        1: FlexColumnWidth(1),
        2: FlexColumnWidth(1),
        3: FlexColumnWidth(3),
      },
      children: [
        TableRow(children: [
          CustomTableCell(child: Text('TABLE CELL')),
          CustomTableCell(child: Text('1')),
          CustomTableCell(child: Text('1234'), hasCircle: true),
          CustomTableCell(child: Text('SOME RANDOM LONG TEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEXT')),
        ]),
        TableRow(children: [
          CustomTableCell(child: Text('TABLE CELL')),
          CustomTableCell(child: Text('1'), hasCircle: true),
          CustomTableCell(child: Text('1234')),
          CustomTableCell(child: Text('')),
        ]),
        TableRow(children: [
          CustomTableCell(child: Text('TABLE CELL')),
          CustomTableCell(child: Text('1')),
          CustomTableCell(child: Text('1234')),
          CustomTableCell(child: Text('')),
        ]),
        TableRow(children: [
          CustomTableCell(child: Text('TABLE CEEEEEELL')),
          CustomTableCell(child: Text('1')),
          CustomTableCell(child: Text('50'), hasCircle: true),
          CustomTableCell(child: Text('')),
        ]),
        TableRow(children: [
          CustomTableCell(child: Text('TABLE CELL')),
          CustomTableCell(child: Text('1')),
          CustomTableCell(child: Text('1234')),
          CustomTableCell(child: Text('')),
        ]),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class CustomTableCell extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final bool hasCircle;

  CustomTableCell({required this.child, this.hasCircle = false});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: child,
        ),
        if (hasCircle)
          Positioned.fill(
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: CircleWidget(),
            ),
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class CircleWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 40,
      height: 40,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        border: Border.all(
          color: Colors.red,
          width: 2.0,
        ),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
            blurRadius: 5,
            spreadRadius: 2,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


Thank you, this is close, but in your example the red circle is contained within the cell. The question is how to implement this example so the circle spans over multiple adjacent cells.

I ended up creating a concept of layers. Basically rendering the same table on 2 layers. The base layer is the table without circles, the second layer is the same table with the circles and the cells rendered as transparent. This way, the "circle" layer positions the circles correctly but everything that could cover the circles is transparent.
